# Is there a better way to display different text while looping and asking for the same variable without adding X while loops?

Tags: c++, c, loops, while-loop

When making a program that loops asking for the same variable multiple times and displaying some text that is different each time.Is there a more efficient way of doing that without having x amount of while loops?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

 int main(void){

int loopcount;
int grade;
int avg;
int total;

total = 0;
loopcount = 0;

/* Displays "Enter your FIRST Grade" then stores the entered number in the variable grade
it then adds it to total and adds 1 to the loopcount */

while(loopcount<1){
printf("Enter your first grade: ");
scanf("%d", &grade);
total = total + grade;
loopcount = loopcount += 1;
}

/* Does the same thing but prints Enter your SECOND grade */
while(loopcount<2){
printf("Enter you second grade: ");
scanf("%d", &grade);
total = total + grade;
loopcount = loopcount += 1;
}
 // etc etc

avg = total/2;
printf("Your average is %d", avg);

getch();
}
```

Comment: `loopcount = loopcount += 1;` should probably just be `loopcount += 1;`

Comment: Why are there loops at all? It looks like each one only runs once.

Comment: I was just trying to get the point across that I'd like to ask for the same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static array with the info you want to by different:

```
static const char * const ordinal[] = { "first", "second" };
while(loopcount<2){
    printf("Enter your %s grade: ", ordinal[loopcount]);
    scanf("%d", &grade);
    total = total + grade;
    loopcount = loopcount + 1;
}
```